# Why can't I run explain on MongoDB update?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to explain a mongoDB update; but nothing is happening? Does Mongo not support this?

```
> db.movies.update({"actors.name": "Christian Bale"}, {$set: {"actors.$.name": "Christina Bale"}}, {$explain: 1});
>
```

I've tried other variations using `.explain()` and `._addSpecial("$explain", 1")`. Both of these produce the following error:

> Thu Aug  1 11:26:46.368 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Cannot call method 'explain' of undefined

Comment: did you ever have any luck getting performance information on an update?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe the following will allow you to call explain on your query.

```
    db.movies.explain().update({your_query})
```

Hope this helps, if you need more info let me know.

Comment: This worked for version 3.4; should probably be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to call explain on update? AFAIK, explain will show you how your query will fetch the rows, so you could simply do:

```
db.movies.find(
    {$query:  {"actors.name": "Christian Bale"}},
    {$explain: 1}
);
```

Comment: This produces an error as well: `> db.movies.update({$query:{{"actors.name": "Christian Bale"},{$set: {"actors.$.name": "Christina Bale"}}}},{$explain: 1});
Thu Aug  1 11:31:41.958 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>`

Comment: I was interested in the time it takes to update a set of rows as well as other information

Comment: @LoganBailey The log will tell you better

Comment: Another example: what if you have constraints and you want to see if it provokes a scan?